# Calculate the sum and show data in frontend

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a React code that shows JSON data in a tabular form. And there is a button, on click of which, I want to total the column's data, add it to a new column (`sum`), and display. Here is my code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const NewTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { val: 2, val2: 3, val3: 1 },
    { val: 4, val2: 1, val3: 9 },
    { val: 6, val2: 1, val3: 1 }
  ]);
  const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
  const processData = () => {
    data.map((item) => {
      var currRowValues = Object.values(item);
      var nd = currRowValues.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + b;
      });
      return (item["sum"] = nd);
    });
    setData(data);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {keys.map((item, idx) => (
              <th key={idx}>{item}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, idx) => (
            <tr>
              {keys.map((key, idx) => (
                <td key={idx}>{item[key]}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={processData}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewTable;
```

Currently, the new row is getting added when I save the code but not when I click on the submit button. How can I fix this? [Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-heyrovsky-pywgwu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is a working fiddle of the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mistaking the use of `Array.map`. `Array.map` will create a new array and apply what is return from the call back function on each element, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). With that said, the `setState` in `processData` will basically do nothing since your data is not change and you're setting state with what you initialize the state with. To use the new map value, you can assign that to a variable or constant and use that like below:

```js
...
const processData = () => {
    var rowWithSum = data.map((item) => {
      var currRowValues = Object.entries(item);
      var nd = currRowValues.reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
        if(key === 'sum'){
          return a
        }
        return a + value;
      }, 0);
      return {...item, sum: nd};
    });
    setData(rowWithSum);
};
...
```

I've also modify so that it create a new key in the object using spread operator, which you can read more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and also to not accidentally add the existing sum to the next sum by check the key using `Object.entries`.

Comment: To add some points to this answer; `map` does return a new array but in this case since the array is made up of objects and while returning in the original code the object itself is modified with a new key, `data` does actually get updated. As to why the code in question did not work I'm not fully sure, but there is a concept of not modifying a state variable directly. You should always make a copy of the variable and then set it. In this case it can be done by `Array.from(data)` and then using that in map and ultimately for setData.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting a re-render because React does a referential equality comparison of props/state when making a decision to re-render.

`data` has the same reference as the original state `data` array because of which the functional component does not re render on setData

Change `setData(data)` to `setData([...data])` which returns a new copy of the array.

You can have a look on how to update objects and arrays in state - https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state